# Webkit text gradient with random colors using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want certain text on a webpage to be displayed in a left to right color gradient, where the colors are selected randomly from a list. Here's my HTML

```
<div id="randomgrad">Random Gradient</div>
<script src="randomgradient.js"></script>
```

Here's my CSS

```
#randomgrad {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 72px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

and here's the script

```
var colors = ['#58D68D', '#F1C40F', '#68C4EC', '#EC7063', "#F39C12", "#979A9A", "#40B5AD", "#A52A2A"];
randcol = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
randcoltwo = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
gradcol = '-webkit-linear-gradient(left,' + randcol + ' ,' + randcoltwo + ')';
document.getElementById('randomgrad').style.background = gradcol;
```

What I get is the background with the gradient with random colors, but no text. So somehow the background-clipping is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) works with `background-image` and `background-color` (rather than `background`). In your case - a linear/radial gradient set through javascript, you need to use `backgroundImage`

```js
var colors = ['#58D68D', '#F1C40F', '#68C4EC', '#EC7063', "#F39C12", "#979A9A", "#40B5AD", "#A52A2A"];
randcol = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
randcoltwo = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
gradcol = '-webkit-linear-gradient(left,' + randcol + ' ,' + randcoltwo + ')';
document.getElementById('randomgrad').style.backgroundImage = gradcol;
```

```css
#randomgrad {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 72px;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="randomgrad">Random Gradient</div>
```